# angular 2 asset not updated in the server

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I have added a new folder '**font**' inside my asset folder which has my customised fonts and i added a css file for the same in side the css folder.

I can see them inside **dist** folder but it is not available when i deploy in a server.

inside source code:
[image]

Inside source tab in chrome:
[image]

Comment: @WilliamHampshire no you don't. You need to configure your angular-cli.json correctly. In angular 2 you should almost never be adding things directly to index.html.

OP: we need to see your cli.json file

Comment: Can you share your code where you have linked to these fonts and with your folder structure?

Answer (score -1):

Are you using custom font for icon?

You may not able to see fonts file in Chrome source tab.

Check the network tab to verify that http request is sent for font file or not?
If it is a font-icon and you are using from CSS, check the css to verify relative path for font.

[Chrome network tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fVRDO.png)

Regards,
Rajul

Comment: check how to answer in stack overflow